Excel hangs in Python script to export excel as a pdf in Task Scheduler, but works normally
I'm trying to just automate creating a pdf from an excel file to email it out everyday. It should be simple, but it isn't. If I run these files in command line, they will run, create the pdf, and close out of excel correct.
But if I run it in task scheduler, not only does it refuse to create the pdf, but Excel hangs and doesn't exit properly.
I've tried it in python and powershell
Python wincom32
from os import getenv
from os.path import basename
from pathlib import Path
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, time
import pythoncom
import os
import shutil
import time
from win32com import client
import win32com.client as w3c


today = datetime.now().date()
path = "C:\\scripts\\"

excel_path = os.path.join(path , 'Book1.xlsx')
pdf_path = os.path.join(path ,'book1.pdf')

#convert to PDF
pythoncom.CoInitialize()
excel =  w3c.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
sheets =  excel.Workbooks.Open(excel_path)
work_sheets = sheets.Worksheets[1]
work_sheets.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, pdf_path)

sheets.Close(False)
excel.Workbooks.Close()
excel = None
pythoncom.CoUninitialize()

running the script:
python c:\scripts\pycom.py

Python xlwings
import os
import xlwings as xw

book = xw.Book(r'C:\\scripts\\Book1.xlsx')
sheet = book.sheets("Sheet1")

current_work_dir = os.getcwd()
pdf_path = os.path.join(current_work_dir, "Book1.pdf")

sheet.api.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, pdf_path)

app = xw.apps.active 
app.quit()

running the script
python c:\scripts\xlwings.py

powershell
param (
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$ExcelFilePath,  # Path to the Excel file
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$WorksheetName,  # Name of the specific worksheet
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$OutputFolderPath  # Path where PDF files will be saved
)

try {
    $excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
    $excel.Visible = $false
    $excel.DisplayAlerts = $false

    $workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($ExcelFilePath)
    $worksheet = $workbook.Worksheets.Item($WorksheetName)

    # Generate the PDF file path (customize as needed)
    $pdfPath = Join-Path -Path $OutputFolderPath -ChildPath ($workbook.Name -replace '\.xlsx?', '.pdf')

    # Export as PDF
    $xlFixedFormat = "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFixedFormatType" -as [type]
    $worksheet.ExportAsFixedFormat($xlFixedFormat::xlTypePDF, $pdfPath)

    $workbook.Close()
    $excel.Quit()
}
finally {
    # Release COM objects
    $worksheet, $workbook, $excel | ForEach-Object {
        if ($_ -ne $null) {
            [void][System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($_)
        }
    }
}

powershell
cd c:\scripts\
.\ConvertToPDF.ps1 -ExcelFilePath "c:\scripts\Book1.xlsx" -WorksheetName "Sheet1" -OutputFolderPath "c:\scripts\"

I've tried using a bat file to run the python scripts
start "C:\Python3_10\python.exe" "C:\scripts\pycom.py"

I tested it with my complex excel file and my simple one. My simple file is just a book1.xlsx with the word blah in cell A1.
My Task Manager
I've tried the following
[
[
I have it run with the highest privileges

And these settings

I've tried to investigate the event viewer, and through research, I found this article and followed the steps, but it didn't work. Excel still hangs in task scheduler, and my pdf doesn't get created.
https://shauncassells.wordpress.com/2015/09/28/windows-10-event-10016-fix-the-application-specific-permission-settings-do-not-grant-local-activation-permission-for-the-com-server-application-with-clsid-d63b10c5-bb46-4990-a94f-e40b9d520160-and-a/
I've also tried giving Python Schedule a try and this still causes excel to hang in the task manager and it also doens't create the pdf. I'm not sure what's going on.
import schedule
import time
import subprocess

def xlwings_daily():
    subprocess.run(['python', 'xlwings.py'])
def pycom_daily():
    subprocess.run(['python', 'pycom.py'])

schedule.every().day.at('08:49').do(xlwings_daily)
schedule.every().day.at('08:55').do(pycom_daily)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)

My goals are

It runs every day.
The PDF is created.
Excel is not hanging in Task Manager.


I've seen a similar problem before somewhere, and there were some working fixes that I usually use just in case.

Make Python sleep with time.sleep(value) for some time after sending Close() or Quit() command to Workbook or Excel application (process can be long on Excel side and bork smth on it's way out).
Nullify your variables containing app and/or workbook before closing the Python itself:

excelapp = w32cl.DispatchEx('Excel.Application')
wb = excelapp.Workbooks.Open(path)
...
wb.Close(True)
wb = None
excelapp.Quit()
excelapp = None


More radical solution - get PID of spawned Excel process and kill it forcefully (with os, psutil or other modules):

excelapp = w32cl.DispatchEx('Excel.Application')
tid, pid = win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(excelapp.Hwnd)
...
os.kill(pid, signal.SIGTERM)


To clarify - my answer mainly cover the hanging Excel part.
Maybe you need to activate your environment for packages to be imported before you start the script. It's definitely the move if you have smth like Conda.
Also I can suggest to try using the .bat file as a wrap over your script - it's easier to manage some commands in txt format rather than use form-like Task Scheduler options for process, working directory, flags, etc.
